# What can I put in the namespace for WCF?

Tags: wcf

I just started learning on WCF and is trying to create a WCF service for my client application.

From the msdn tutorial, I have went through all the individuals steps and sort of grasp how WCF works and now I am trying to start coding the service on my part. For the first step it says, defining a service contract. and the sample code msdn gives are as follows

```
namespace Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples 
{
    class Program
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

and the service contract.

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples")]
```

what i would like to ask is, what can i actually substitute the namespace with since I am developing for my own application?

Comment: If you don't need it, just don't specify it at all

Comment: what do you mean by don't specify it?

Comment: you don't have to set `Namespace` property if you don't need it, just `[ServiceContract]` will suffice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The namespace can be a string - typically it's a URI, like in your question, but it could also be a simple dotted namespace

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples")]
```

Answer (score 3):

Contract namespaces are just strings to resolve possible conflicts (can be useful when versioning, for example). If you omit it your WSDL will contain http://tempuri.org. Not what you want in production. However, it's not that easy to just set proper name in `ServiceContractAttribute`, there are also binding and schema namespaces. For better understanding WSDL namespaces in context of WCF I highly recommend [this blog post](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/kirillg/archive/2006/06/18/28380.aspx).